# Is my Proof Correct: $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ $\sigma-$finite measure space then $\mu^{*}(B) < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, outer-measure

My proof is different to my professor's and I wanted to ensure that mine is still correct and I am not overlooking something.

So: Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma-$finite measure on $X$. Show that for $B \in \mathcal{A^{*}}$ (which is the system of $\mu^{*}-$measurable sets), $\mu^{*}(B) < \infty$.

First the obvious: $B \subseteq X$. Moreover, from $\sigma-$finite measure we get  $\exists (A_{n})_{n} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ so that $X \subseteq \bigcup_{n}A_{n}$ and $\mu(A_{n})<\infty$.

Well $\mu^{*}(B) \leq \mu^{*}(X)$, however, from Caratheodory we know that $\mu^{*}(X)=\mu(X)$, since $ X \in \mathcal{A}$

and $\mu(X)\leq\mu(\bigcup_{n}A_{n})\leq\sum_{n}\mu(A_{n})<\infty$ q.e.d

Is this correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think this is not correct.  Since for a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$, it's not necessarily the case that $\mu(X) < \infty$ (ie. the sum in the final line of your proof may not converge, it might diverge to infinity).  I am interested to give this problem a try myself

Comment: Could you give me an extensive example wherein $\mu(X)=\infty$, while $\mu$ is $\sigma-$finite on $X$

Comment: Lebesgue measure for example.  The real line can be expressed as a union of intervals [k,k+1] where k varies through the integers.  Each interval has Lebesgue measure 1, and $\sum_{z\in \mathbb{Z}} 1 = \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Let's try inserting $B$ into your decomposition of $X$.  Notice that if $X\subseteq \cup_{n}A_n$ as in your proof attempt, then since $B\subseteq X$, we can write
$$X = B \cup \left(\bigcup_{n} (A_{n}\setminus B)\right)$$

Then $\mu (B)<\infty$ since $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite since, and $\mu (B) = \mu^{*} (B)$ since $B \in A^{*}$ **(this last claim I am unsure about)**